# Query grants for a table in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-grant

How can I query all GRANTS granted to an object in postgres?

For example I have table "mytable":

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT ON mytable TO user1
GRANT UPDATE ON mytable TO user2
```

I need somthing which gives me:

```
user1: SELECT, INSERT
user2: UPDATE
```

Answer (score 148, accepted):

I already found it:

```
SELECT grantee, privilege_type 
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='mytable'
```

Answer (score 117):

`\z mytable` from psql gives you all the grants from a table, but you'd then have to split it up by individual user.

Comment: would you run this directly from the sql pane or pg command line?

Comment: @DanielL.VanDenBosch: all the meta-commands, like `\z`, are for psql. And psql is the command-line interface to PostgreSQL.

Comment: \dp tableName does the same thing.

Answer (score 52):

The query below will give you a list of all users and their permissions on the table in a schema.

```
select a.schemaname, a.tablename, b.usename,
  HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename, quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename), 'select') as has_select,
  HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename, quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename), 'insert') as has_insert,
  HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename, quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename), 'update') as has_update,
  HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename, quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename), 'delete') as has_delete, 
  HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename, quote_ident(schemaname) || '.' || quote_ident(tablename), 'references') as has_references 
from pg_tables a, pg_user b 
where a.schemaname = 'your_schema_name' and a.tablename='your_table_name';
```

More details on `has_table_privilages` can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-info.html).

Comment: This is the only answer here that computes permissions obtained from membership in other roles, so it gets my vote. On the other hand, I would say `has_table_privilege(usename, contact(schemaname, '.', tablename), ...)` to avoid ambiguity.

Comment: Plus One - THIS IS PURE GOLD!

Comment: Finally someone gave the right answer

Answer (score 34):

If you really want one line per user, you can group by grantee (require PG9+ for string_agg)

```
SELECT grantee, string_agg(privilege_type, ', ') AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE table_name='mytable'   
GROUP BY grantee;
```

This should output something like :

```
 grantee |   privileges   
---------+----------------
 user1   | INSERT, SELECT
 user2   | UPDATE
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Almost what I want, can I have the exact `GRANT`s like pg_dump outputs?

Answer (score 11):

This query will list all of the tables in all of the databases and schemas (uncomment the line(s) in the `WHERE` clause to filter for specific databases, schemas, or tables), with the privileges shown in order so that it's easy to see if a specific privilege is granted or not:

```
SELECT grantee
      ,table_catalog
      ,table_schema
      ,table_name
      ,string_agg(privilege_type, ', ' ORDER BY privilege_type) AS privileges
FROM information_schema.role_table_grants 
WHERE grantee != 'postgres' 
--  and table_catalog = 'somedatabase' /* uncomment line to filter database */
--  and table_schema  = 'someschema'   /* uncomment line to filter schema  */
--  and table_name    = 'sometable'    /* uncomment line to filter table  */
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4;
```

Sample output:

```
grantee |table_catalog   |table_schema  |table_name     |privileges     |
--------|----------------|--------------|---------------|---------------|
PUBLIC  |adventure_works |pg_catalog    |pg_sequence    |SELECT         |
PUBLIC  |adventure_works |pg_catalog    |pg_sequences   |SELECT         |
PUBLIC  |adventure_works |pg_catalog    |pg_settings    |SELECT, UPDATE |
...
```

Comment: this gives only the rows matching the user who executed it ... not all grants

Answer (score 5):

Adding on to @shruti's answer

To query grants for all tables in a schema for a given user

```
select a.tablename, 
       b.usename, 
       HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename,tablename, 'select') as select,
       HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename,tablename, 'insert') as insert, 
       HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename,tablename, 'update') as update, 
       HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename,tablename, 'delete') as delete, 
       HAS_TABLE_PRIVILEGE(usename,tablename, 'references') as references 
from pg_tables a, 
     pg_user b 
where schemaname='your_schema_name' 
      and b.usename='your_user_name' 
order by tablename;
```

Comment: This works well, assuming you log in as a user with appropriate permissions. Nitpick: I advise that a cross join should be written explicitly, e.g. `FROM pg_tables AS a CROSS JOIN pg_user AS b` rather than the SQL 92 way of doing it with a comma `from pg_tables a, pg_user b`

Answer (score 3):

Here is a script which generates grant queries for a particular table. It omits owner's privileges.

```
SELECT 
    format (
      'GRANT %s ON TABLE %I.%I TO %I%s;',
      string_agg(tg.privilege_type, ', '),
      tg.table_schema,
      tg.table_name,
      tg.grantee,
      CASE
        WHEN tg.is_grantable = 'YES' 
        THEN ' WITH GRANT OPTION' 
        ELSE '' 
      END
    )
  FROM information_schema.role_table_grants tg
  JOIN pg_tables t ON t.schemaname = tg.table_schema AND t.tablename = tg.table_name
  WHERE
    tg.table_schema = 'myschema' AND
    tg.table_name='mytable' AND
    t.tableowner <> tg.grantee
  GROUP BY tg.table_schema, tg.table_name, tg.grantee, tg.is_grantable;
```

Here the statement if you want to get it for views:

```sql
 SELECT 
    format (
      'GRANT %s ON TABLE %I.%I TO %I%s;',
      string_agg(tg.privilege_type, ', '),
      tg.table_schema,
      tg.table_name,
      tg.grantee,
      CASE
        WHEN tg.is_grantable = 'YES' 
        THEN ' WITH GRANT OPTION' 
        ELSE '' 
      END
    )
  FROM information_schema.role_table_grants tg
  JOIN pg_views v ON v.schemaname = tg.table_schema AND v.viewname = tg.table_name
  WHERE
    tg.table_schema = 'myschema' AND
    tg.table_name='myview' 
    AND tg.grantee <> 'myschema'
  GROUP BY tg.table_schema, tg.table_name, tg.grantee, tg.is_grantable
```