# GRANTs in generated CREATE statement from pgAdmin

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequence, sql-grant, pgadmin

If I create the following sequence in Postgres:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
GRANT ALL ON SEQUENCE test TO testuser;
GRANT SELECT ON SEQUENCE test TO testuser2;
```

And then select the sequence in pgAdmin, right mouse click -> CREATE script, I get:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE test
  INCREMENT 1
  MINVALUE 1
  MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
  START 1
  CACHE 1;
ALTER TABLE test
  OWNER TO testuser;
GRANT ALL ON TABLE test TO testuser;
GRANT SELECT ON TABLE test TO testuser2;
```

So in the GRANT statements I see the keyword "TABLE" and not "SEQUENCE"

1. Why is that?
2. How is pgAdmin generating the DDL extract?

This question is related to one of my other questions here:
[Query GRANTS granted to a sequence in postgres](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7337662/query-grants-granted-to-a-sequence-in-postgres)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PostgreSQL, sequences are kind of like tables.

> The catalog pg_class catalogs tables and most everything else that has
>   columns or is otherwise similar to a table. This includes indexes (but
>   see also pg_index), sequences, views, composite types, and TOAST
>   tables; see relkind.

[PostgreSQL docs for pg_class](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/catalog-pg-class.html), one of the system catalogs (system tables)

Comment: But how does PgAdmin create staements like "GRANT ALL ON TABLE test TO testuser"? OK, the ACL information is available in column "relacl" of pg_class, but it takes some programming effort to tranform something like "{postgres=arwdDxt/postgres}" into "GRANT SELECT ...", nearly impossible to do this with pure SQL. Isn't there somewhere a table similar to information_schema.role_table_grants for sequences?

Comment: @markus: Sorry for the delay; I overlooked your comment. I don't know how pgAdmin generates SQL for its SQL pane, but you can [download the source code](http://www.pgadmin.org/download/source.php). As far as I can tell, there's no information_schema view that exposes the privileges for sequences.